# Negative Value in Covid-19 Dataset

Tags: dataset

I am currently practicing my data visualization skills with [ourworldindata dataset](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/README.md). I noticed there is a negative value of `new_cases` in Benin country. Out of curiosity, what does that mean? I mean, why would the `new_cases` has a negative value?

Here is where the negative value is found.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that number is calculated from the total_cases column. Value = "total_cases from day before" - "total_cases of that day". In this case: -209 is 130 - 339. Not sure why that number would decrease, but could be they changed the way they count, or just an error in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they found out that they wrong identified 209 patient as positive and when they found out that they just subtracted those wrong result to make the total case correct.